# What is the proper regex syntax for a IIS URL Rewrite rule where a URL does NOT contain a string?

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewrite-module

I am trying to write a regex Expression for the IIS 8.0 URL Module where:

(the URL *is* **/en**
*OR*
the URL starts with **/en/**)
*AND* 
the URL does ***NOT*** contain **switchLanguage=true**)

I have the following rule in my web.config...

```
<rule name="Remove Default Language" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(^en$|^en/(.*)$)(?&lt;!switchLanguage=true(.*))" />
    <conditions>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

... but this causes a 500.52 error to be thrown with a message that the match syntax is not valid.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.   It appears to be that I was trying to accomplish too much using the RegEx script.

The following rule works -- note the negate condition.

```
<rule name="Remove Default Language" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^en$|^en/(.*)$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="switchlanguage=true" negate="true" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```